How to get 'session' parameter when using python imouapi library?
I am trying to use the imouapi library, but at the moment of initializing the api_client, I see that it asks for an argument inside the function, which is called session. How can I generate this argument to pass it to the function? I have already read the documentation, but I can't find anything about it.
from imouapi.api import ImouAPIClient

# Credentials
APP_ID = 'abc'
APP_SECRET = 'def'

# Initialization
api_client = ImouAPIClient(app_id=APP_ID, app_secret=APP_SECRET, session=????)


try this:
import aiohttp
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    # Utworzenie klienta API
        api_client = ImouAPIClient(app_id, app_secret, session)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
